# Centre Google Maps on Responsive Website

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps

I am using a Google Map on my website through an API. It works fine however I have two additional bits of code. One to make it responsive and one to keep it centred. For some reason I can't integrate both bits of code at the same time.

Here's the current working code (with responsive part):

```
<script>
    var map;
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-40.893591, 132.023621);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            draggable: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            navigationControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
           };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        // init Height
        $('#map_canvas').height($( window ).height());
        });
        // On Resize
        $(window).resize(function(){ 
        $('#map_canvas').height($( window ).height());});

      var center;
function calculateCenter() {
  center = map.getCenter();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
  calculateCenter();
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map.setCenter(center);
});

});
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens when you try?

Comment: The map disappears! Its the way I'm adding the code I think.

Comment: check F12 console log for errors.

Comment: The error is: initMap is not a function.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the code block you're attempting to use?  We have no idea where or how you're attempting to add the second code block to the first.

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {  $(document).ready(function() { `<--Duplicated, you only need one initialization... `$(document).ready(function(){` ...just as a comment. Your error "initMap" is called somewhere, try to check where and then, remove it if you're not using it, also, works on normal browsers? becuase if works, then, is the "$(window).resize" the issue. You don't need to set the height for centering, the responsive works by itself, because is not supposed to be resized the browser after the first load

Comment: Both pieces of code work individually, but when I put them together then it doesn't work! Ill try your suggestion.

Comment: I know they works, by that I mean you don't need both, only 1.

Comment: I'm not getting an error: http://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/8te6209k/1/

Comment: Strange... When I copied the JSFiddle the map showed! However the map is still not centring when the window size is changed... Any ideas?

Comment: The event is triggering, so I would start by logging the value of "center" to make sure it's what you expect.  You may need to control the order in which the idle and resize events fire.

Comment: @devlincarnate Found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var lnglat = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: lnglat,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      draggable: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      navigationControl: false,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
    });

      var center;
function calculateCenter() {
  center = map.getCenter();
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'idle', function() {
  calculateCenter();
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  map.setCenter(center);
});

  }
    </script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_ID&callback=initMap">
</script>
```